# Azure REST API for Azure AD settings

Tags: azure

I need to get information about the already configured User Settings from Azure AD through API.
I'm looking for the request with information about "Guests can invite" is set to "No" or "Members can Invite" is set to "No"
Could you please provide me information about the required API call for my purpose?

Comment: I have a feeling these are not available in any API

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Powershell to achieve this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/delegate-invitations#assign-the-guest-inviter-role-to-a-user

Unfortunately it is not possible as of yet to make direct Microsoft Graph calls to add app role assignments. Please follow the GitHub issue : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4155 for an official response.

It is possible to add a new directory role to a user via the AddDirectoryRole API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript

Hope this helps!